# jquery mobile tabs not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs

I am using jquery mobile tabs to display two tabs, but the problem is the second tab shows by default, I want the first tab to show by default. Also, when I click on the other tab, nothing happens...

Does anyone know whats wrong?

tutorial link: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/

Thanks

```
    <div id="map-page" data-role="tabs" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <div id="map_canvas" role="main" class="ui-content">
                <!-- map loads here... -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce with your code, it works as it should, but you may be able to force whatever is changing the tab with `data-active="0"` to specify the first tab.

```
<div id="map-page" data-role="tabs" data-theme="b" data-active="0">
```

You probably want to see the [API Docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tabs/) as well, note the similarities with jQueryUI Tabs.